# How compiler finds template best match and evaluates expressions

Tags: c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae, template-specialization

My question is naive but help me out to understand if my reasoning is correct. Here's the code I develop after watching part of a video conference of Walter E. Brown about metaprogramming. The code works. My question is more about how the compiler matches and evaluates the expressions.

```
//1 - Matches "simple" type. 
template <typename T_>  
struct mySizeof
{
    static constexpr size_t size = sizeof(T_);
};

//2 - Matches arrays of type T_ and size N.
template <typename T_,size_t N> 
struct mySizeof<T_[N]>
{
    //3 - What is T_ at this point??? 
    static constexpr size_t size = N * mSize<T_>::size;     
};

int main()
{
    using int_t = int;
    using int_arr = int[10][50][100];

    std::cout << mySizeof<int_t>::size << ":" << sizeof(int_t) << std::endl;
    std::cout << mySizeof<int_arr>::size << ":" << sizeof(int_arr) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

//Parsing & evaluating int [10][50][100]
// 1.1 - Matches T_ = int[10][50][100]. But there's a better match.
// 1.2 - Better match. T_ = int, N = 10.
// 1.3 - Since [10] was consumed, lets check the remain expression. T_ becomes [50][100]. ???
// 2.1 - Matches T_ = int[50][100]. There's a better match.
// 2.2 - Better match. T_ = int, N = 50. 
//....
// 4.1 - It matches. T_ -> int
// 4.2 - Doesn't match.
```

I just need to understand at this point how compiler evaluates and finds out the best match, and how does it perform argument substitution.

Comment: Is `mSize` supposed to be `mSizeof`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your schema

Parsing & evaluating `int [10][50][100]`

1.1 - Matches `T_ = int[10][50][100]`. But there's a better match. [right]

1.2 - Better match. `T_ = int, N = 10`. **[wrong: `N=10, T_=int[50][100]`]**

1.3 - Since `[10]` was consumed, lets check the remain expression. `T_` becomes `[50][100]`. [`T_ = int[50][100]`, see 1.2]

2.1 - Matches `T_ = int[50][100]`. There's a better match. [right]

2.2 - Better match. `T_ = int, N = 50`.  **[wrong: `N=50 and T_=int[100]`]**

....

4.1 - It matches. `T_` -> `int` [right]

4.2 - Doesn't match. [right]

(p.s.: If I'm not wrong, SFINAE isn't involved; only specialization.)

A simple test

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>  
struct mySizeof
 { static constexpr std::size_t size { sizeof(T) }; };

template <typename T, std::size_t N> 
struct mySizeof<T[N]>
 {
   static constexpr size_t size { N * mySizeof<T>::size };     
   using type = T;
 };

int main ()
 {
   using T0 = int[10][50][100];

   using T1 = typename mySizeof<T0>::type;
   using T2 = typename mySizeof<T1>::type;
   using T3 = typename mySizeof<T2>::type;

   static_assert( std::is_same<int[50][100], T1>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<int[100],     T2>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<int,          T3>::value, "!" );
 }
```